# Executors.newFixedThreadPool - issue

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have used CopyOnWriteArrayList collection object which holds 1000 URLs. each URL indicates a file.

I want to use Multithread pooling mechanism to download those URL files parallel.

Tried using below code :

```
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> fileList = DataExtractor.getRefLinks();

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    CompletionService<String> pool = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(
            threadPool);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size() ; i++){
        pool.submit(new StringTask(fileList));
    }
```

This is hitting the same URL 4 times. Might have done something wrong. Could you please suggest where it went wrong ?

My requirement is to pick 4 URLs (threads) at a time and start downloading them parallel till all the URLs in the List finish downloading.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what `StringTask` is, but you seem to be passing the full list of URLs to it. Make the appropriate changes to only submit a single URL from the list

```
pool.submit(new StringTask(fileList.get(i)));
```

(Or use an iterator over the `fileList`, whichever is more appropriate for a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.)

```
for (String url : fileList){
    pool.submit(new StringTask(url));
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for spontaneous reply. This was the mistake i was doing : for (String url : fileList)

Comment: Once all the URLs  are downloaded, program is not getting terminated, any clues ? thanks.

Comment: Shutdown the executor.

Comment: yeah, just realized, threadPool.shutdown(); - served my purpose.